# Largest provably existing ordinal in ZF without power set

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

If I remove the power set axiom from ZF, but retain the axiom of infinity, what will be the largest ordinal that can still be proven to exist. Or, if no largest such ordinal exist, what is the limit ordinal of all ordinals that can still be proven to exist. Of course, it is possible that even in this extended sense no such largest ordinal exists.

---

As Asaf convinced me, there is no need to modify the axiom of replacement or the axiom of foundation for the question to make sense in this context. However, the question as initially intended was about a useful set theory without the power set axiom (i.e. a theory one would use occasionally). As I gather from  Miha Habič's comment, this would have been Kripke-Platek set theory (plus the axiom of infinity), and the largest provably existing ordinal would be $\omega_1^{CK}$ in that case.

Comment: Why do you need to remove or adjust other axioms? The language does not have a symbol for the power set anyway.

Comment: My gut intuition is $\omega_1$ is the sup of ordinals constructible without power set, but don't hold me on this.

Comment: This is an excellent question!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to allow removal or adjustment of the other axioms to remove potential difficulties unrelated to my basic question. Basically, I'm interested in (a simple model of) a set theory provably containing the hereditarily finite sets plus at least one infinite set. From [On interpretations of arithmetic and set theory](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ndjfl/1193667707), I already know that adjustment of the axiom of foundation may be a good idea in this context.

Comment: If you have infinity and replacement then there's no adjustment needed.

Comment: @Kris But $\omega_1$ is awfully big. I was expecting/"hoping for" something smaller or equal to $\epsilon_0$, based on the fact that ZF with infinity negated is "said to be" bi-interpretable with Peano arithmetic.

Comment: @Thomas: If anything then I expect it to be closer to $\omega_1^{CK}$ or even larger. $\varepsilon_0$ is too small... It seems to me that one can use replacement to prove its existence.

Comment: Can't we just argue that if the supremum was countable (and necessarily a limit ordinal), we can find a sequence of length $\omega$ converging to it and then apply replacement to construct the supremum?

Comment: Also, I agree with Asaf that if this supremum is countable, it should be at least $\omega_1^{CK}$. This is because any model of ZF - Power Set is a model of Kripke-Platek set theory and $\omega_1^{CK}$ is the least height of such a model above $\omega$.

Comment: IIUC, strictly speaking, the answer to your question as written is "there is none": If there was a largest provably existing ordinal $o_{\text{max}}$, then you could prove the existence of $o_{\text{max}}+1>o_{\text{max}}$, in contradiction to the assumption that $o_{\text{max}}$ is the largest provably existing ordinal.

Comment: The question asks about ordinals that "can be proven to exist in every model of the axioms". That presupposes that one can compare ordinals from different models. That seems fine if we're talking about well-founded models, but if we take the phrase "every model of the axioms" literally, then some clarification is needed. Such models will, for example, have elements that are $\omega$ in the sense of the model but have predecessors beyond the usual natural numbers.

Comment: To add on @Andreas' point, there is some point where ordinals are not really nameable anymore. For example, given $\alpha$ a countable ordinal such that $\alpha={\sf Ord}^M$ for some $M$, a countable transitive model of $\sf ZFC$, then there is $\beta<\alpha$ such that $\beta=\omega_1^M$ and then $(H(\omega_1)^M$ is a model of $\sf ZF-Pwr$. So even if we restrict ourselves to transitive models, we can't prove the existence of any ordinal larger than $\omega_1$ of the least transitive model. But it seems to me that the question here is slightly different, about *internal* characterization.

Comment: Similarly, seeing how $H(\omega_1)^M$ is a model of $\sf ZF-Pwr$, then taking any countable elementary submodel, and then collapsing it, would be a model of these axioms in which there are only a countable set of ordinals. Taking the least ordinal which is not in such submodel, that would also be a least upper bound. If we take it up one notch, then we can do this trick in the least transitive model, and we can probably get that least ordinal there. But does it have a name?

Comment: I certainly don't believe that $\omega_1^{CK}$ is the least ordinal with this property. There's a huge difference in the powers of expressibility between $\sf KP$ and $\sf ZF-Pwr$. The former only has a very limited schemata of separation and replacement, whereas the latter has a lot more. That been said, you haven't commented about Andreas Blass' comment, or my follow ups to that comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You may be right. All I know is that in a transitive model of Kripke–Platek set theory containing $\omega$, all ordinals (from the outer-set theory) smaller than $\omega_1^{CK}$ will be present. This doesn't necessarily imply that this is also provable in KPI, because there might also be other (i.e. non-transitive) models.

Comment: I meant to say that I think that it might be that the existence of $\omega_1^{CK}$ is provable in $\sf KPI$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila wrote: "you haven't commented about Andreas Blass' comment, or my follow ups to that comment." Well, I hoped that my edit to the question would address that comment. (I removed the "in every model of the axioms" part, and tried to clarify what I mean by "largest cardinal". But of course, it is still possible that no such "largest cardinal" exists.)

Comment: Well, the point is that we can take a model of these axioms which has non-standard integers. So not even $\omega$ is an actual element of that model.

Comment: I don't think that the existence of $\omega_1^{CK}$ itself is provable in KPI, because that would imply the existence of $\omega_1^{CK}+1$. I think $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is a model of KPI which doesn't contain $\omega_1^{CK}+1$, but I might be wrong and just mix different meta-levels.

Comment: But you're not asking about $\sf KPI$. You're asking about a stronger theory.

Comment: Yes, the question is now explicitly about the stronger theory, with the added note that the answer to my initially intended question is probably $\omega_1^{CP}$. I was replying to your comment "...is provable in **KPI**", but I guess that's just a typo and no real confusion.